Upper bound of depressed quartic
For the depressed quartic equation $x^4-ax^2-bx-c=0$, $a,b,c>0$, is there some (relatively easy) way to find an upper bound of the positive root in terms of $a,b$ and $c$? I am aware of Ferrari's solution for the depressed quartic, but that requires completing the square which gives a very complicated expression.
Context: I am reading an article in which they state that for $a,b,c,x>0$, if $x\leq a\sqrt{x}+bx^{1/4}+c$, then $x\leq C(a^2+b^{4/3}+c)$ for some $C>0$. By plotting, it seems that the statement is true for $C=2$, but I cannot prove it. I was thinking to perform the substitution $t=x^{1/4}$ which gives us a depressed quartic equation to solve, hence the question. The exact value of $C$ is not important, so the upper bound need not be optimal, I just need to find basically any upper bound in terms of $a,b$ and $c$.
Thanks in advance for any replies.

The following result has not been officially recognized by the mathematical community, and all I can do is guarantee that it is absolutely correct.
If the depressed quartic $x^4+ax^2+bx+c=0$ has four real roots $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ (meaning the coefficients $a, b, c$ are also real numbers), including multiple roots, then the following inequalities will hold:
$c>0\Rightarrow |x|\leq \sqrt{\frac{b^2}{4c}-a}$
$c<0\Rightarrow |x|\leq \sqrt{\frac{27}{34}}\sqrt{-\frac{b^2}{4c}-a}$
The first of these two inequalities corresponds to the case where the equation has two positive and two negative roots, while the other inequality corresponds to the case where three of the roots of the equation are all positive or all negative (the fraction $27/34$ within the radical may seem arbitrary, but it is perfectly accurate). For a random depressed quartic with four real roots, these inequalities usually give a value very close to the value of the root with the maximum absolute value.

Thank you for your answer. How would you go about showing these inequalitites?

Thanks, Luis.These inequalities arise from the geometric interpretation of the solution of a depressed quartic having two positive and two negative roots. In any other case, some of the parameters of the geometric construction take on complex values ​​and hence its design is generally impossible, but it still works algebraically.
https://freeimage.host/i/JvkJ8iJ
